# Link and enum to get value from resx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, webforms, resx

i want to use enum as a key to get value from an resource file
in my project i use and method to get value from resx file:

```
using System;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Resources;
    using System.Web;
    using Utility.Tools.ExtensionMethods;
    using Utility.Tools.Infrastructure;
    using Utility.Tools.Utilities.Storage;

    namespace MultiLanguage
    {
        public enum LocaleConfig_Type : byte
        {
            FA,

            AR,

            DARI
        }

        public class MultiLangToolkit
        {
            public static string GetTranslate(MainKeys key)
            {
                var lang = LanguegesToolkit.GetCurentLang();

                return GetTranslate(key, lang);
            }

            public static string GetTranslate(MainKeys key, LocaleConfig_Type locale)
            {
                try
                {
                    string value;
                    switch (locale)
                    {                        case LocaleConfig_Type.FA:
                            {
                                var fa_resx = new ResourceManager("MultiLanguage.FA", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                                value = fa_resx.GetString(key.ToString());
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocaleConfig_Type.AR:
                            {
                                var ar_resx = new ResourceManager("MultiLanguage.AR", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                                value = ar_resx.GetString(key.ToString());
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocaleConfig_Type.DARI:
                            {
                                var dari_resx = new ResourceManager("MultiLanguage.DARI", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                                value = dari_resx.GetString(key.ToString());
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            value = "No Language Selected!";
                            break;
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                        return value;

                    return "Key Or Value NotFound!";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return "Exception when translate";
                }
            }
        }

        public class LanguegesToolkit
        {
            public static LocaleConfig_Type GetCurentLang()
            {
                try
                {
                    object sessionDefalutLocale = null;

                    if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
                    {
                        sessionDefalutLocale = HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionManager.SESSION_USER_DEFAULT_LOCAL];
                    }
                    if (sessionDefalutLocale != null)
                    {
                        return sessionDefalutLocale.ToString().ToEnum<LocaleConfig_Type>();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var defaultLocale = RequestGlobalProperties.CurrentUserRequest.DefaultLocale;

                        if (defaultLocale.IsNullOrEmpty())
                            return Constants.ServiceDefaultLocale.ToEnum<LocaleConfig_Type>();

                        return defaultLocale.ToEnum<LocaleConfig_Type>();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return LocaleConfig_Type.FA;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and i have a enum class to store enums:

```
namespace MultiLanguage
{
    public enum MainKeys
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// login to account
        /// </summary>
        Sign_in,

        /// <summary>
        /// password
        /// </summary>
        Password,

        /// <summary>
        /// user name
        /// </summary>
        Username
}
}
```

and i use this code to get value from my resx files

```
 MultiLanguage.MultiLangToolkit.GetTranslate(MultiLanguage.MainKeys.Username)
```

but this type of code is too many for getting a value from my resx file
i just want to write this code instants the code above:

```
 MultiLanguage.MainKeys.Username
```

simply just call the enum and get translated value from resx file
i use this code in a dll file to use that in my other projects and use and enum as a key instants of string because strings is not a good choice and my cause and runtime issue and it's hard to debug that. and using summery on the enums to see that is the value in resx file(yes i copy the value frome my rex file into summery)
how can i do that?
is that possible ?

Comment: Instead of using an Enum, change the `MainKeys` to a static class and change all the enum variables to static properties. Implement their getters as such: `public static string Username { get { return MultiLanguage.MultiLangToolkit.GetTranslate("Username"); } }`

Comment: The usage of this will then be: `string userNameResource = MultiLanguage.MainKeys.Username;`

Comment: @OguzOzgul tnx for your comment but it's too much, i have to repeat one thing on all props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to stick with your enumerations then you could just create an extension method to simplify the usage.  Something like

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
  public static string Translate(this MainKeys key)
  {
    return MultiLanguage.MultiLangToolkit.GetTranslate(key);  
  }
}
```

then you can just use

```
MultiLanguage.MainKeys.Username.Translate();
```

Comment: tnx for your good answer but i have to add this to my own project, but i have multiple project and i dont want to add any class or adding using in any page of my project. all most be in a dll file,is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Just put this in the same dll where your enum is defined and give it the same namespace then wherever you reference that enum, this extension will be available.